# How do I get debug logging out of php_fastcgi in a container?

Tags: docker, php-fpm, fastcgi, caddy, php-fastcgi

I am running a container built from [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/oberonamsterdam/docker-php/blob/master/php82/Dockerfile). It's running a basic PHP application. In front of it I have [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/php_fastcgi). A lot of people put nginx in front of PHP. I don't and I won't. So if your suggestion is "use nginx" or "use apache" please don't reply.

**Note**: the process of writing a good question caused me to find my problem. It turns out it was a Caddy problem. I needed to specify `root /app` in the `php_fastcgi` directive, as shown in the Caddy docs. I no longer get the 404s I was getting. However, I still don't know how to get better debugging out of FastCGI in my container, so I'm leaving the question open because that is still of interest to me. (I didn't understand how that `root` parameter was used in the FastCGI connection)

Here's the relevant [Caddy directive](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/php_fastcgi) in my `Caddyfile`.

```
new.example.com {
    root * /nfs/www/example/html
    php_fastcgi example-container:9000 {
        root /app
    }
    file_server
}
```

I've created a file named `test.html` with some really basic contents:

```
<html>
<head><title>paco test</title></head>
<body>
<p>This is a test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I put this file in `/nfs/www/example/html/test.html`, and then I visit `https://new.example.com/test.html` I get the web page delivered exactly as expected. If I copy the file to `test.php`, which should invoke the PHP engine I get an error 404. In the PHP container's logs, I simply see:

```
172.21.0.5 -  23/Mar/2024:16:30:41 -0400 "GET /test.php" 404
```

The PHP docker container doesn't see the request for `test.html` because Caddy serves that directly. The point of sharing this is to suggest that Caddy is doing the right thing and the PHP container is receiving the requests it should. That's why my question is a PHP/FastCGI question, and not a Caddy/nginx/apache question.

Now, if someone has a fix for my problem, that's awesome (i.e., how to make FastCGI PHP actually find the right PHP file and execute it), but I'm really just asking for how to turn on more verbose logging in the FastCGI container. I can't figure out what file path it was trying to open when it failed to find `test.php`. I can't get anything more verbose than that `/test.php 404` line in the log. I can't find any other logs inside the container itself.

As far as I can tell, this docker container intends to run `php-fpm` in a current working directory of `/app`. If I use `docker exec` to get a shell in the container, I see all my files in `/app` (e.g., `/app/test.php`) and all the file permissions are fine. Here's the chunk of my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
  example:
    image: oberonamsterdam/php:8.2-fpm
    container_name: example
    user: "1006:1006"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /nfs/www/example/html:/app/:cached
    environment:
      - "PHP_SESSION_SAVE_HANDLER=redis"
      - "PHP_SESSION_SAVE_PATH=tcp://redis:6379"
      - TZ=EST5EDT
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - caddy
```

I've done a bit of searching and I have turned on a few options in my PHP container. In my `php-fpm.d` config files I have some directives like these:

```
catch_workers_output = yes
decorate_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

I've been able to use `docker exec` to run `bash` in the container, and I can run `php test.php` and get the expected output. So this is obviously some kind of FastCGI thing.

Any ideas how to get more FastCGI / PHP debugging out of this container?

Comment: what is the output, while using curl and the origin port outside?